# how to make div to new line

Tags: html, css

i am beginner to css.

i want to make new div into new line like this,

[image]

i try my code like this

```
<style>
div{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
}

.one{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
.three{
    width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.four{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
background:darkblue;
}
.five{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
background:blue;
}
 </style>

<div class="one">image</div>

<div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>

<div class="one">image</div>

<div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>

<div class="one">image</div>

<div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>
```

but result like this

[image: result of the code]

how to move, the second image to new line..
pls anybody help me. i ll appreciate your answer

Comment: why not try using tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div{
  /*display:inline-block;*/  /* deleted */
  /*float:left;*/            /* deleted */
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
}

.some {
    margin-bottom: 10px;   /* new */
}

.one{
  float: left;  /* new  */
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}

.three{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.four{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
background:darkblue;
}
.five{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="some">
    <div class="one">image</div>

    <div class="three">
        <div class="four">name</div>
        <div class="five">desc</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="some">
    <div class="one">image</div>

    <div class="three">
        <div class="four">name</div>
        <div class="five">desc</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="some">
    <div class="one">image</div>

    <div class="three">
        <div class="four">name</div>
        <div class="five">desc</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

separate each block ( here i added a div with class name `some` )

and as you want one side `.one` and another side `.three`  so just add `float:left;` on `.one`

Comment: thank you for all responses..this is what i need..tks a lot..you save my morning (indonesia time)

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this.

```css
.box-wrapper {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .box-wrapper:before, .box-wrapper:after{
      clear:both;
      display:table;
      content:"";
    }
    .box-tall {
        width: 50%;
        background:#ded9d9;
        height: 200px;
        float: left;
    }
    .box-left {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
    .box-1 {
        background: #8f8fde;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .box-2 {
        background: #d2c47a;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
      <div class="box-tall">
         tall
      </div>
      <div class="box-left">
        <div class="box-1">top</div>
         <div class="box-2">bottom</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `clear:both` or `clear:left` to make the div to be displayed in the new line

Comment: thank you for quick response, in which div i put it ? sorry i am  beginner

Comment: You should add to the style of the images

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below. you were not clearing out your floats.

```
<div class="one">image</div>

<div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>


<div class="one">image</div>

<div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>

<div class="one">image</div>

<div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>


div{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
}

.clearfix{
  clear:both;
}

.one{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  display:block !important;
}
.three{
    width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.four{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
background:darkblue;
}
.five{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code after style tag

```
<div class="one">image</div>

<div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="one">image</div>

  <div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="one">image</div>

<div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>
```

I think this is what you want to do

Hope it helps

Let me know if you require any further help

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the float on your `.one` div.

This is the only part that would change:

CSS:

```
.one{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  clear:left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

You may want to consider altering your markup as well by wrapping each group of `divs`, but this will get you what you need.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k4dw68pg/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.
try this code out :

```
<style>
div{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
}

.one{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  clear:both;
}
.three{
    width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.four{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
background:darkblue;
}
.five{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
background:blue;
}
 </style>

<div class="one">image</div>

<div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>

<div class="one">image</div>

<div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>

<div class="one">image</div>

<div class="three">
  <div class="four">name</div>
  <div class="five">desc</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div to wrap your group of image/name/desc and then set `clear: both;` to this div:

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
}

.image-wrapper {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.one{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
.three{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.four{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
  background:darkblue;
}

.five{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <div class="one">image</div>

  <div class="three">
    <div class="four">name</div>
    <div class="five">desc</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image-wrapper">
  <div class="one">image</div>

  <div class="three">
    <div class="four">name</div>
    <div class="five">desc</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image-wrapper">
  <div class="one">image</div>

  <div class="three">
    <div class="four">name</div>
    <div class="five">desc</div>
  </div>
</div>
```